How can I add extra buttons to the asset browser header?
I recently got the True Terrain addon and it added these buttons the the header of the asset manager. I was wondering how they did that and if I could make my own to better organize all of my assets

Hello, I took the liberty to shorten a bit the title of your question so it's more easily parsable, feel free to revert if you don't like it. Cheers

You need to append (or prepend) a function callback to the header class to draw your custom layout.
import bpy

def draw(self, context):
    self.layout.label(text="Hello World")

bpy.types.ASSETBROWSER_MT_editor_menus.append(draw)

